# Java - renameTo method not working

Tags: java, rename

I'm trying to use the **renameTo** method in Java but it just returns false and doesn't move the file.

Am I missing a step?  Is there a way to find out why it's not moving the file?  The **delete** method doesn't do anything either.

Here's my code showing how I'm using it:

```
private void archiveOutputFile(File outputFile) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmssS");
    String timeStamp = formatter.format(new Date());
    String subFolderName = "Archive" + timeStamp;
    File subFolder = new File(outputFile.getParent(),subFolderName);
    subFolder.mkdir();
    File newFile = new File(subFolder,outputFile.getName());
    //outputFile.deleteOnExit(); //Doesn't work, nor does .delete()
    boolean success = outputFile.renameTo(newFile);
}
```

Here's some system info:

Java: 1.6.0_21; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 17.0-b17

System: Windows XP version 5.1 running on x86; Cp1252; en_US (nb)

Comment: The file is probably locked by the OS. Did you create the file in your code as well? If so, did you `close()` it (or the stream writing to it)?

Comment: Can you confirm that the old and new files are on the same filesystem?

Comment: @bart: I don't have a close method available on the file.  I'm passing it to Weka to parse the file.  I'd have to assume Weka would close the file once it's done.
@Zach: Yes, they're on the same file system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot rename or delete a file which Windows consider to be open.

Comment: Turns out the Weka DataSource class I was sending the file to was somehow locking the file.  I changed to use a constructor where I could send it an input stream instead of a file path and then closed the input stream myself.  That ended up working.

Comment: It is enough that the file is opened and not closed yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the subfolder before you move the file into it (uncomment subFolder.mkdir();)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check for exists. `public boolean exists()`

[More here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Answer (score 0):

it works, if I comment in the line

```
subFolder.mkdir();
```

Comment: Well obviously, the problem was that the subfolder didn't exist.  The `renameTo()` method won't create directories for you.

Comment: I tried it that way too with no luck.  (I just updated the question.)